# need to add "_corrupt_record" column explicitly in the schema if you need to do schema validation when reading json via spark

Tags: json, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, rdd

When I read JSON through spark( using scala )

```
val rdd = spark.sqlContext.read.json("/Users/sanyam/Downloads/data/input.json")
val df = rdd.toDF()
df.show()
println(df.schema)

//val schema = df.schema.add("_corrupt_record",org.apache.spark.sql.types.StringType,true)
//val rdd1 = spark.sqlContext.read.schema(schema).json("/Users/sanyam/Downloads/data/input_1.json")
//rdd1.toDF().show()
```

this results in following DF:

```
+--------+----------------+----------+----------+----------+--------------------+----+--------------------+-------+---+---------+--------------+--------------------+--------------------+------------+----------+--------------------+
|   appId|    appTimestamp|appVersion|  bankCode|bankLocale|                data|date|         environment|  event| id|  logTime|       logType|                msid|                muid|       owner|recordType|                uuid|
+--------+----------------+----------+----------+----------+--------------------+----+--------------------+-------+---+---------+--------------+--------------------+--------------------+------------+----------+--------------------+
|services| 1 446026400000 |    2.10.4|loadtest81|        en|Properties : {[{"...|user|af593c4b000c29605c90|Payment|  1|152664593|AppActivityLog|90022384526564ffc...|22488dcc8b29-235c...|productOwner|event-logs|781ce0aaaaa82313e8c9|
|services| 1 446026400000 |    2.10.4|loadtest81|        en|Properties : {[{"...|user|af593c4b000c29605c90|Payment|  1|152664593|AppActivityLog|90022384526564ffc...|22488dcc8b29-235c...|productOwner|event-logs|781ce0aaaaa82313e8c9|
+--------+----------------+----------+----------+----------+--------------------+----+--------------------+-------+---+---------+--------------+--------------------+--------------------+------------+----------+--------------------+

StructType(StructField(appId,StringType,true), StructField(appTimestamp,StringType,true), StructField(appVersion,StringType,true), StructField(bankCode,StringType,true), StructField(bankLocale,StringType,true), StructField(data,StringType,true), StructField(date,StringType,true), StructField(environment,StringType,true), StructField(event,StringType,true), StructField(id,LongType,true), StructField(logTime,LongType,true), StructField(logType,StringType,true), StructField(msid,StringType,true), StructField(muid,StringType,true), StructField(owner,StringType,true), StructField(recordType,StringType,true), StructField(uuid,StringType,true))
```

If I want to  apply validation for any further json I read then I take schema as a variable and parse that in `.schema` as an argument *[refer the commented lines of code]*, but even the corrupt records don't go into `_corrupt_record` column(which should happen by default), instead it parses that *bad records* as null in all columns and this is resulting into data loss as theie is no record of it.
Although when you add `_corrupt_record` column in schema explicitly everything works fine and the corrupt_record goes into the respective column, I want to know the reason why this is so? 
(Also, if you give a malformed Json, spark automatically handles it by making a `_corrupt_record` column, so how come schema validation needs explicit column addition earlier) ??

Answer (score 1):

Reading corrupt json data returns schema as `[_corrupt_record: string]`. But you are reading the corrupt data with `schema` which is wrong and hence you are getting the whole row as null.
But when you add `_corrupt_record` explicitly you get whole json record in that column and I assume getting null in all other columns.

Comment: the code above works fine after I uncomment the commented lines and my bad-record comes in `_corrupt_record` column after parsing with all other columns as null. I just want to know the reason why you need add that column explicitly before...because in case of malformed json spark handles creates that column itself.

Comment: @SanyamJain You don't have to add the `_corrupt_column` explicitly if you don't pass the `schema` while reading the data. But if you do spark will expect data to be in that format only and doesn't return you `_corrupt_column`. So bottom line if you explicitly specifying schema you have to pass `_corrupt_column` explicitly as well.